# How to stop the current command only in a bash script?

Tags: bash, signals, sigint

Suppose that `sleep 180` is a command that requires some time.
I have a script that looks like this

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Before sleep"
sleep 180 # I want to stop this
echo "After sleep"
exit 0
```

I want that, when the user press CTRL+C while `sleep` is executing, only this is terminated so that the user sees "After sleep".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution while I was writing here.

The solution was writing on top of the script this simple signal handler:

```
#!/bin/bash    

# subroutine
on_int(){
    echo
    echo "Stopping current command..."
}

# register signal handler subroutine for SIGINT
trap on_int SIGINT
# ...
```

In this way the `sleep` command is stopped but the script continues whit the next commands.